# Visualizar vídeo de Camera IP

Tags: php, ip, streaming, vídeo

Senhores, eu não sou nenhum perito em PHP, estou começando agora, e gostaria de uma direção em como exibir o vídeo da minha Camera IP - P2P

snapshot.php

```
<?php
    $img="http://usuario:senha@ipddns:portacamip/mjpeg.cgi?user=usuario&password=senha&channel=0&.mjpg"; 
    readfile($img); 
?>
```

index.php

```
<img src="http://meudominio.com/snapshot.php" width="640" height="380" name="refresh">

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">     
    image = "http://meudominio.com/snapshot.php"
    function Start() {
    tmp = new Date();
    tmp = "?"+tmp.getTime()
    document.images["refresh"].src = image+tmp
    setTimeout("Start()", 300)
    }
    Start();       
</script>
```

O que estou fazendo de errado? Poderiam me explicar por favor?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que o problema está aqui:

```
setTimeout("Start()", 300)
```

O `setTimeout` recebe uma **função** no primeiro parâmetro. O seu caso está executando a função `Start` (que, pelo fato de ser em forma de string, está fazendo um `eval`) e passando o **resultado da função** para `setTimeout`.

O correto seria:

```
setTimeout(Start, 300)
```

Comment: O caminho do vídeo está correto?

Comment: Se o arquivo `snapshot.php` está na raíz do site e o domínio está correto, sim

Comment: Ah, show de bola então, assim que chegar em casa, testarei

Comment: Tem alguma dica rápida de redirecionamento de portas? como funciona?

Comment: Não entendo disso

Comment: qual o tratamento que eu poderia fazer para verificar a existencia desta variável ou arquivo? `$img="http://usuario:senha@ipddns:portacamip/mjpeg.cgi?user=usuario&password=senha&channel=0&.mjpg";`

Comment: Isso seria [outra pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) :)